# Microsoft Excel 2010 if(or(and I am confused

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am trying to query two cells by using If function but unfortunately have no luck. I will give you an example below. Please let me know how I can solve this issue.

If C2="Car" and D2="Toyota_Mazda" then I want it to show "Toyota"

If C2="Car" and D2="Toyota" then I want it to show "Toyota"

If C2="Car" and D2="Mazda" then I want it to show "Mazda"

If C2="Lux Car" and D2="BMW" I want it to show "BMW_Merc"

If C2="Lux Car" and D2="BMW_Merc" I want it to show "BMW_Merc"

I hope this makes sense.

Thanking you for your help in advance.

Comment: What if it's "lux car" but "Rolls Royce"? In principle this is a simple if statement nested in the right way but you need a proper decision table to define the 2/4/8/16 outputs.

Comment: Could there be a case: C2="Car" and D2="BMW"?  It isn't clear from your question that the result depends on the value in C2.  You might be able to just test D2.

Answer (score 1):

Requirements like these are almost always incomplete. One possible formula to get the result as asked in the question is

```
=IF(C2="car",IF(LEFT(D2,6)="Toyota","Toyota",IF(LEFT(D2,5)="Mazda","Mazda","some other car")),IF(AND(C2="Lux Car",LEFT(D2,3)="BMW"),"BMW_Merc","some other car"))
```

For a better answer, you need to create a better question that describes the actual requirement in full.